# Customizing sequelize validation errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, sequelize.js

I've been using sequelize@3.4.1 for a while and now I need to update sequelize to the latest stable version (3.28.0)

**TL;DR: How can I change validation error's structure other than manipulating the 'msg' attribute in the model definition?**

The thing is, I use custom validation messages in all of my models, for example:

```
var Entity = sequelize.define("Entity", {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        validate: {
            isInt: {
                msg: errorMessages.isInt()
            }
        }
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: {
            name: "uniqueNamePerAccount",
            args: [["Name", "Account ID"]],
            msg: errorMessages.unique()
        },
        validate: {
            notEmpty: {
                msg: errorMessages.notEmpty()
            }
        }
    },
    accountId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: {
            name: "uniqueNamePerAccount",
            args: [["Name", "Account ID"]],
            msg: errorMessages.unique()
        },
        validate: {
            isInt: {
                msg: errorMessages.isInt()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Until sequelize@3.4.1 I used to add my own attributes to the validation error, so in fact the messages were objects that contains the message and other attributes like inner error code.
Here's an example of the messages:

```
function notEmpty() {
    return {
        innercode: innerErrorCodes.notEmpty,
        data: {},
        message: "cannot be empty"
    };
}
function unique() {
    return {
        innercode: innerErrorCodes.unique,
        data: {},
        message: util.format("There is already an item that contains the exact same values of the following keys")
    };
}
```

In fact, This how the Entity used to look like:

```
{"name":"SequelizeValidationError",
 "message":"Validation error: cannot be empty",
 "errors":[{"message":"cannot be empty",
            "type":"Validation error",
            "path":"name",
            "value":{"innercode":704,
                     "data":{},
                     "message":"cannot be empty"},
            "__raw":{"innercode":704,
                     "data":{},
                     "message":"cannot be empty"}}]}
```

So basically sequelize found my 'msg' attribute and appended it into the value of the error.
But now, in the latest version, It looks like sequelize throwing new Error(): (instance-validator.js line:268)

```
throw new Error(test.msg || 'Validation ' + validatorType + ' failed');
```

Instead of the error that was thrown in 3.4.1 version:

```
throw test.msg || 'Validation ' + validatorType + ' failed';
```

Because of that, the error object I set as a custom message is shown as 'Object object' (most probably after toString())

**My question is:** How can I influence the error's structure and add more attributes other than message?

**P.s:**
I have problems with the unique constraint custom message too, It's different because it's not considered as a validator.
How can I influence the unique constraint error structure?

Thank you very much!